# Where to change in source code rendering Hebrew text with dots? PDF JS

Tags: javascript, html, text, pdf.js

I have to show pdf books in Hebrew, but the Hebrew alphabet has 2 styles of text (with dots and without dots).

When book has text style with dots - appear issues occur: when I select text - it randomly has spaces in one word and also problems with search.

So I want to change text rendering function and implement it.

HTML:

```
Enter input text here:<br/>
<textarea id="input" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea><br/><br/>

Enter output text here:<br/>
<textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea><br/><br/>

<button id="convert" onClick="doStrip()">
Strip Vowels
</button>
```

JS/JQuery

```
function stripVowels(rawString)
{
    var newString = '';
    for(j=0; j<rawString.length; j++) {
        if(rawString.charCodeAt(j)<1425
             || rawString.charCodeAt(j)>1479)
        { newString = newString + rawString.charAt(j); }
    }
    return(newString);
}

/* @shimondoodkin suggested even a much shorter way to do this */
function stripVowels2(rawString) {
  return rawString.replace(/[\u0591-\u05C7]/g,"")
}

function doStrip() {
   var input = $('#input').val();
   var output = stripVowels(input);
   $('#output').val(output);
}
```

[link to Fiddle editor](https://jsfiddle.net/js0ge7gn/)

example text (copied from book, seems pdf js wrong render spaces): לּעַ , עִ גוּוֵּ ן, רִ  בָּ  רָ  ה, מַ לְ בׁ: מְ צֻ לָ ע, צֶ לַ ע, קָ דְ  קֹד, זָ וִ ית יְ שָ   ג ִ  י םׂמֻ   ש

hope when I will change characters with dots into characters without dots 
 in rendering function - it will solve this issue

I also try to change SPACE_FACTOR, but still have issues

Comment: Where and how does [tag:pdfjs] enter into this exactly…?

Comment: @deceze I am using ng2 pdf viewer - wrapper of pdf js in Angular8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in file evaluator.js 
in function buildTextContentItem
do what you needed with variable "glyphUnicode"